# How to initialize a struct with dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization

I want to initialize every time a struct with dictionaries. Later, I'm going to use its properties instead a dictionary's keys and values - it seems rather easier. However, when I try the code below, it tells me that "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" and "1. 'self.one' not initialized" and "2. 'self.two' not initialized". My question is how to initialize a struct from a dictionary, so that I have basically a struct with the contents of the dictionary? Or how to transform it into struct?

```
struct Blabla {
    var one: String
    var two: [Int]

    init(three: [String: [Int]]) {
        for i in three {
            self.one = i.key
            self.two = i.value
        }

    } ERROR! - Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I suspect this has something to do with the conditional nature of setting `self.one`, `self.two` in the for loop.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A `[String: [Int]]` (a.k.a. `Dictionary<String, Array<Int>>`) has multiple key value pairs, each one consisting of one string, and multiple ints (in an array). In your code, if `three` is empty, `self.one` and `self.two` are never set, and if it has more than `n` entries, they're overwritten `n-1` times, so that their final value is the last key/value pair of the dictionary (which itself is indeterminate, because dictionaries have no defined ordering)

Answer (score 1):

struct Blabla {
    var one: String
    var two: [Int]

```
init(three: [String: [Int]]) {
    one = ""
    two = []
    for i in three {
        self.one = i.key
        self.two = i.value
    }

} ERROR! - Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`for in` clause may have zero runs, in which case struct properties will not be initialized. You have to provide default values (or emit fatalError if you really need to).

While I think your example is pure synthetical, there is no need to loop through array, you can set properties to its last entry.

Answer (score 1):

This code should compile, but it feels unsafe to me to initialize a Struct in this way because:

- It assume your dictionary has values in it.
- Your stored properties will always have the last value you looped through.
- In order to pull values out to satisfy the compiler you need to force unwrap them. (With Dávid Pásztor's guard-letting approach, this can be avoided)

```
struct Blabla {
    var one: String
    var two: [Int]

    init(three: [String: [Int]]) {
        self.one = three.keys.first!
        self.two = three[three.keys.first!]!
    }
}

let input = ["pizza": [1,2]]
let l = Blabla(three: input)
```

If I were you I would let the memberwise initializer that you get for free do its thing and provide either a specialized initializer to handle your case of taking a Dictionary as input or move that parsing to another function/class/etc....

Comment: OP doesn't want to get first entry but rather last (at least, his code says that) and force unwrapping is not very nice thing in general, especially if you consider that some tools like swiftlint will not pass force unwrapping by default

Comment: Yeah, force-unwrapping is not ideal for sure especially in an initializer.

Answer (score 1):

The issues is that if `three` is an empty `Dictionary`, the instance properties `one` and `two` don't get initialised. Also, you are overwriting the properties in each iteration of the for loop and the compiler cannot guarantee that there will be any iterations of the loop in compile-time, hence the compiler error.

You could make the initialiser failable to account for this by checking that the dictionary actually contains at least one key-value pair and assigning that first key-value pair to your properties.

```
struct Blabla {
    var one: String
    var two: [Int]

    init?(three: [String: [Int]]) {
        guard let key = three.keys.first, let value = three[key] else { return nil }
        one = key
        two = value
    }
}
```

However, you should rethink what it is that you are actually trying to achieve, since with your current setup you have a mismatch between your init input values and the properties of your struct.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error is clear: If the dictionary is empty the struct members are never initialized. But the code makes no sense anyway as each iteration of the dictionary overwrites the values.

Maybe you mean to map the dictionary to an array of the struct

```
struct Blabla {
    let one: String
    let two: [Int]
}

let three = ["A":[1,2], "B":[3,4]]
let blabla = three.map{Blabla(one: $0.key, two: $0.value)}

print(blabla) // [Blabla(one: "A", two: [1, 2]), Blabla(one: "B", two: [3, 4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

struct blabla{
var a : string
var b : [int] = []
init(_ data: [string:[int]]){
// whatever you want to do
}

}